# More pandorean way to lump columns based on pattern and apply function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering if there is a better way to group columns based on a repeating pattern and then apply a function.  Simple version is that I have data by months but want it in quarters.  To get there i need to take each 3 month period and apply mean()

```
    RegionName  State   1997-01 1997-02 1997-03 1997-04 1997-05 1997-06
1   Los Angeles CA      83      19      40      47      76      48
2   Chicago IL          39      87      48      3       71      18
3   Philadelphia    PA  60      85      8       46      81      48
```

Desired result is:

```
    RegionName  State   1997q1      1997q2
1   Los Angeles CA      47.33333333 57
2   Chicago     IL          58          30.66666667
3   Philadelphia    PA  51          58.33333333
```

I have a very hacky way of doing it using python looping and a premade stepped list of numbers:

```
quartersbyendingdigit = {'1':'q1', '4':'q2', '7':'q3', '0':'q4'}
rl = list(range(2, housingdf.shape[1], 3))
for each in rl:
    og_column = housingdf.columns[each]
    new_column = og_column[:4] + quartersbyendingdigit[ og_column[-1] ]
    housingdf[new_column] = (housingdf[housingdf.columns[each]] + housingdf[housingdf.columns[each+1]] + housingdf[housingdf.columns[each+2]])/3
```

I have to imagine that Pandas has a better way to do that since its a very obvious pattern.

Comment: If you transpose the dataframe, each new column will be a time series. You can then apply resampling to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the datetime columns to period of Quarters and then group data frame by columns with `axis = 1`;

```
df.set_index(["RegionName", "State"], inplace=True)    
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).to_period("Q")    
df.groupby(level = 0, axis = 1).mean().reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: Spectacular!  Additional question though:  why does the groupby need a level if doing by columns?  Removing it threw an error.  Is it possible to have a multilevel column structure?

Comment: Yes. It is possible and valid to have multilevel columns in pandas. And that's the reason we need to specify the *level* parameter here.